# SPARQL DBpedia - Retrieve Properties with numbers (DatatypeProperties, xsd)

Tags: properties, xsd, numbers, sparql, dbpedia

So I encountered a Problem on **DBpedia**. Apparently I can retrieve any kind of `property` from a `resource` with the query below, but when the property is from the type `DatatypeProperty` or just a number (`xsd:integer` or something similar) the DBpedia SPARQL Endpoint returns an empty result.

I would like to know what I have to change or even better optional include in my current query to solve this problem.

**Important note:** `Germany` and `population total` are required inputs in my program. Please remember that I must use them.

```
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?objectLabel
WHERE {
      ?subject ?predicate ?object ; rdfs:label "Germany"@en . 
      ?predicate rdfs:label "population total"@en . 
      ?object rdfs:label ?objectLabel 
FILTER (LANG(?objectLabel)='en')
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DatatypeProperty is used to related an individual to a literal and literals can't have any outgoing edge, thus, no `rdfs:label`. If you want to have the lexical form of the literal you can use the `str` function:

```sql
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT (str(?object) as ?value)
WHERE {
      ?subject ?predicate ?object ; rdfs:label "Germany"@en . 
      ?predicate rdfs:label "population total"@en
      FILTER (LANG(?objectLabel)='en')
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Numbers are working now. Is there a way that I can return also the other Properties as labels? I get now ``resources`` instead. E.g.: ``http://dbpedia.org/resource/value``

Comment: Do you have an example property? In general, if it's a resource the idea is the same. Use one more edge that retrieves the label of those resources. That's the whole principle of SPARQL query aka. graph pattern matching.

Comment: No, i meant, for example when i use``"currency"@en`` on ``Germany"@en`` I retrieve now ``http://dbpedia.org/resource/Euro``. If you didn't get my idea. I need a query which can handle numbers **and** also the normal properties from a resource page.

Comment: And I gave you the answer. Add another triple pattern that retrieves the label of the resource object. Is this not clear?

Comment: Query looks like this, but I want to retrieve the string of the number and properties only over the variable ``objectLabel``, not two variables ``objectLabel`` and ``value``..is this even possible?

``PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    SELECT DISTINCT ?objectLabel
    WHERE {
          ?subject ?predicate ?optional ; rdfs:label "Germany"@en . 
          ?predicate rdfs:label "population total"@en .
      
          OPTIONAL { ?optional rdfs:label ?objectLabel FILTER (LANG(?objectLabel)='en')}
          BIND (str(?optional) as ?value)
    }``

Comment: Then do it. And you should omit the predicate label. Otherwise, it returns just a single number. A possible way: `PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?value WHERE { 
?subject ?predicate ?optional ; 
rdfs:label "Germany"@en . 
#?predicate rdfs:label "population total"@en . 
OPTIONAL { ?optional rdfs:label ?optionalLabel FILTER (LANG(?optionalLabel)='en')} 
BIND (if(bound(?optionalLabel),str(?optionalLabel),str(?optional)) as ?value) 
}`